# Tiny Slider: t is not a function when try to work with custom events

Tags: javascript, tiny-slider

I'm using Tiny Slider in Vanilla mode:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.9.4/tiny-slider.css">
<!--[if (lt IE 9)]><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.9.4/min/tiny-slider.helper.ie8.js"></script><![endif]-->

<div class="jobs-slider">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.9.2/min/tiny-slider.js"></script>
<!-- NOTE: prior to v2.2.1 tiny-slider.js need to be in <body> -->

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    /* Tiny Slider */

    var slider = tns({
        container: '.jobs-slider',
        items: 5,
        autoWidth: true,
        slideBy: 'page',
        mouseDrag: true,
        swipeAngle: false,
        loop: true,
        speed: 400,
        navPosition: 'bottom',
        controls: false,
        center: true
    });

    slider.events.on('indexChanged', illuminateSelectedIndex);
    
    var illuminateSelectedIndex = function (info, eventName) {
        console.log(info.event.type, info.container.id);
    }
    
});
</script>
```

The code above is super simple and easy to use. The problem is on the line:

```
slider.events.on('indexChanged', illuminateSelectedIndex);
```

When I use that code, the script `tiny-slider.js` show the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: t is not a function

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the callback first before attaching the listener.

```js
var illuminateSelectedIndex = function (info, eventName) {
  console.log(info.event.type, info.container.id);
}

slider.events.on('indexChanged', illuminateSelectedIndex);
```